# How to efficiently count the total number of one bits in a long sequence of bytes in C?

Tags: c, bit

I was reading the book `programming pearls by Jon Bentley` and I came across this question.

> Given a very long sequence (say, billions or trillions) of bytes, how would you **efficiently** count the total number of one bits? (i.e how many bits were turned on in the sequence)

Most solutions I've seen would not be considered efficient. How do you think this problem can be solved efficiently?

Comment: Build a table of 256 values, each entry denotes the number of bits "lit" in the specified value for that index. `tbl[0] = 0; tbl[1] = 1, tbl[2] = 1, tbl[3] = 2;` etc. Then, for each byte in the stream, accumulate `tbl[b]`, where `b` is the value just-read. That's just one of *many* ways this is doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a CPU that has a `popc16` instruction (which counts the one-bits in a 16 bytes large storage area; popc means population count) and call that in an unrolled loop.

If that is still too slow, split the data into multiple chunks and process them on independent machines. Be careful not to create bottlenecks when splitting or merging the data.

If you are bound to C, check whether your compiler provides a `__builtin_popc` function.

And if even that is not allowed, read the book “Hacker’s Delight”.

Comment: May also be called `__builtin_popcount`.

Answer (score 2):

**Efficient**.

A solution is inefficient when there is a known better solution with no relevant drawbacks, or when the solution does not waste resources when compared against a theoretical optimum solution. For example, we have several *efficient* noisy-channel coding methods that are close to the known theoretical [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_limit).

Unfortunately, when we have several metrics we can choose from -- resources used, power consumed, bandwidth used, latencies incurred --, **efficiency** becomes a vague concept. This is the case with computer algorithms. **Efficient**, in what sense?

Typical desktop and server processors used in 2016 use a multi-level cache architecture, and have arithmetic-logic units that well exceed their main memory bandwidth. Thus, even on architectures that provide a [popcount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popcount) function in hardware, there may be no speed difference to computing the number in each data word using one of the known bit fiddling hacks -- at least when there is too much data to fit in cache.

Often, the *cache footprint* of an algorithm is ignored. If it is large, the algorithm will efficiently use cache in microbenchmarks, giving really nice efficiency figures, but because it pollutes the cache, it may slow down unrelated operations in real life, resulting in "inexplicable" slowdowns of the overall performance. We do not even have any "cache efficiency" metric, because it not only varies between hardware models, but also between workloads, and tasks executed around the algorithm implementation itself.

Even more often, programmers focus on microbenchmarking their code, using the minimal amount of CPU time, but forget that the overwhelming majority of users do not care about that at all, and would just prefer the task to take the least amount of wall clock time instead. In other words, CPU time used is rarely as important to users as *incurred latencies* are. A good example of this is the traditional `sort` program exercise. Most read the file into an array of lines, and then painstakingly optimize a sort function to sort them as needed, as fast as possible. They forget that reading is a slow operation. Reading each line into a sorting data structure, such as a binary search tree, perhaps balanced, or some other tree structure, allows most of the actual sorting be done while the program would otherwise just wait for I/O to complete. The end result is that while the tree approach uses easily more CPU time, it will be faster whenever the I/O takes any appreciable time (i.e., the data is not cached already).

In this particular problem, there are no latency issues, only cache behaviour, that might differentiate solutions. I'd split the implementations in two rough categories:

- Direct bit counting

  Approaches where each byte or word (unsigned integer unit) is analyzed, and a running sum of set bits is kept.

  The number of bits set in a byte or word can be counted either using a `popcount()` type function, or via table look-up.
- Histogram of values; result is a dot product between the histogram and the number of bits set in each bin index

  For example, an approach could use `1U << CHAR_BIT` entries (of type `size_t` in C) to count the number of different `unsigned char` values seen in the memory region. Afterwards, the total number of set bits seen is the sum of each entry multiplied by the number of bits set in the respective value ([OEIS A000120](http://oeis.org/A000120), but usually just counted using a `popcount()` function).

In some contexts the time taken by tallying the number of set bits may be important (either due to security reasons, if this happens to be a part of some security mechanism, or because this is done in a hardware interrupt context and the jitter caused is easiest to manage if it is always roughly the same duration), the histogram approach may well be preferable -- more *efficient* -- although it looks like an inefficient one at first encounter.

Direct bit approach can be done inefficiently in many ways. For example, your C compiler might not expose the hardware `popcount()` function at all, or it might emulate it somehow stupidly. On microcontrollers, the table lookup might reside in Flash, which may be slower to access than SRAM. There might not be enough SRAM available for the histogram approach, either.

While it is easy to show something to be inefficient by simply showing a way that has fewer downsides, it is not possible to claim something to be **most efficient** without knowing the exact metric for the comparison, exactly how the efficiency between completely different approaches is measured.

Fortunately, OP asked *how to ... efficiently*. That is good. Unfortunately, because there are many ways to be efficient, there are many ways to do the task specified, with hardware and context differences dictating which one is "best" or more efficient than another.

It would have been even better to ask *"which approach has the least downsides to ..."*. In my opinion and experience, it would be a direct approach that used `unsigned long` units for the bulk of data, `unsigned char` for leading unaligned and trailing bytes, and a `popcountl()` function that counts the number of bits set in an unsigned long. The function would use `__builtin_popcountl()` if the [compiler is GCC](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/), and a `static inline` function based on one of the bit twiddling hacks otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Roland's answer, an efficient way to get the number of 1's in an unsigned (or 4-bytes at a time) is the following bitwise hack (which I believe comes from either hacker's delight or bit twiddling hacks)

```
int getn1s (unsigned x)
{
    x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    x = x + (x << 8);
    x = x + (x << 16);
    return x >> 24;
}
```

which if inlined and called in an unrolled loop summing the results should provide a fairly efficient way of computing the number of 1's in as many bytes as you have.